# Where to seek translations of research articles

Tags: translation

I am collecting a large number of research articles from the historical record on a particular topic (comparative prime number theory). A good handful of them—about 10-15 or so spanning the 20th century—are written in German.

How does one go about (seeking or) soliciting translations into English of full papers, on this scale?

The translations don't have to be utterly perfect, but they should be professional-level translations—meaning we should be confident that mathematicians who read the English translations should get out of it the same mathematical content that someone reading the German original would get.

Comment: You might be able to pay some German colleagues or their grad students to do it. Have you tried this?  I can't see any other way you'd be able to have it done (I doubt that most professional translators are familiar with the appropriate mathematical German)

Comment: Translation of mathematics into English will likely be of poor quality unless the translator knows mathematics.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar I agree—hence my inquiry on this site and not a non-specific translation site.

Comment: I am willing to interpret (as opposed to translate) certain texts from German.  I can probably recreate my notes from E. Westzynthius's 1931 paper, if that is of interest.  Gerhard "It's In My Personal Interest" Paseman, 2018.11.10.

Comment: If you are mostly interested in the mathematical content, you might also try to translate them yourself. Statements and their proofs usually involve only a quite limited vocabulary, and the process is in a way self correcting, since you'll have enough mathematical knowledge to see if you end up with a correct proof. It will be a slow process in the beginning, but I'll guess a few papers in, you'll get quite fluent in reading mathematical German.

Comment: I don't know if there is a number theory mailing list like there is for algebraic topology and category theory, but if there is, you might do well to actually post an advertisement there with how much you're willing to pay per paper/page and see if any of your German colleagues in the field have grad students willing to do it for pay.  You could probably get a much better deal doing it this way, especially if you're willing to do final proofreading yourself.  At Elsevier's price, you're paying somewhere in the neighborhood of $80-100 per page.

Comment: I would be optimistic to find German Master or PhD students who are interested in this kind of work.

Comment: @Greg Martin I will suggest that once translated the paper should be posted in arXiv. Translation of some (some 60 papers) of Euler's papers are posted in arXiv.  I have translations of several German number theory papers, but to Spanish, so I have not posted them in arXiv.

Comment: @GregMartin --- wouldn't there be a copyright issue with posting to arXiv? (since copyright only expires 70 years after the author has passed away, it is likely that 20th century texts are still copyrighted).

Comment: @Carlo Beenakker. Sometime, somewhere we will find a place where copyright laws are dictated to defend the authors. Mathematicians are all glad to see his works read. Mathematicians do not get any from all the paywalls we find in our papers.

Answer (score 19):

[Elsevier](https://webshop.elsevier.com/languageservices/translationservices/pages/ourtranslators.html) offers a translation service at a rate of € 0.22 per word for a German to English translation. They promise that the translation will be at the level suitable for publication in one of their professional journals, without the obligation to actually submit to one of their journals. You might try them out.

I know, this is a for-profit company, but I don't see how you can do this with volunteers, without payment.

---

A different issue is how you will handle the math. You could simply OCR the German publication and provide the translator with the German text without the math, but in particular for inline symbols this may be confusing. I have in the past used [InftyReader](http://www.inftyreader.org) to convert a scanned document into LaTeX, including the equations. Some post-processing is needed, but it might be an efficient solution.

Comment: Wait... the price per word is the same from German to English and from English to German? What about German compound words?

Comment: I understand that the standard for translation price is wordcount in source language---you are not paid for writing too long sentences in target language! I guess german compound words is counted as one word, after all, they **are** one word.

Comment: :%s/ //g (sorry)

Answer (score 7):

Like you, I struggle to decipher  articles in German.  The older  influential  articles (before 1980) were all translated in Russian by top Russian mathematicians . If you can read Russian I highly recommend  these translations. Often they are better than the original since the translations occurred several years after the original publication and  they  often  include  as appendices  surveys of  what happened since the publication.  Many typos  and mathematical errors  in the original were corrected, and sometime in the footnotes you can find sketches of different arguments.

Another approach I  am using relies on Google Translate. It   has improved  considerably and I have used it successfully to read German articles, one paragraph at a time.   The translation is not perfect  but close enough so you can figure out yourself the mathematical arguments.